# Daniel or Danel

Tags: mesorah-tradition, ezekiel--the-book, daniel-the-person

These days I saw an exegete argue that the Daniel in Ezekiel 14:14 and 28:3 does not refer to the Daniel of the homonymous book but to Danel of the Epic of Aqhat, who according to the Book of Jubilees would be the father-in-law of Enoch. He supports this thesis on the basis that in Ezekiel 14:14 Danel appears among non-Israelite characters, Noah and Job. He also maintains that the Hebrew text has two constructions, a defective writing דנאל and a full דניאל because of the "Yud" and that the text in question is a qere, that is, written is Danel but the Masoretes want us to read Daniel being a proposal to camouflage mythological aspects present in the text by inserting a more historical figure, this is his thesis, this he decoded from the BHS that refers to Masorah Parva that appears in the qere. This being, what would this impact on the text since there is this character appearing in Jewish tradition as Enoch's father-in-law?

Comment: Off-topic: This reminded me of Chaka of the Unas. Anyone else?

Comment: What would be the problem with reading Danel instead of the Masoretic proposal Daniel? Why does Massorah send this qere? It's a simple and even innocent question, how could this cause embarrassment since there is a character with the same name in an apocryphal book?

Comment: side note: most meforshim identify this as "the" Daniel.

Comment: Which text? Of Ezekiel or of the Jubilees? The problem with dealing with this is that it seems to clash with tradition and Hebrew is a traditional language, but what appears in the original text does not contain this “Yud” and this refers to the qere of Masorah Parva. No one knows the name of God but in the tetragram everyone learns to read Adonai and not just any other expression, this is not the name, rather a proposal to read the tetragram in a respectful way

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by the impact on the text? Are you asking whether Jews should accept the spelling דנאל and pronounce the name Danel in reading as well or are you asking how one is to understand Ezekiel's words in light of such an interpretation?

Comment: My doubt is what would change if the proposal to understand that this individual in Ezequiel is not the one in the homonymous book, but a character that appears in an apocryphal book? Would it change so much that it needs to be understood to be Daniel for some reason we don't understand?

Comment: and here I thought the name fo the book is דנייאל

Comment: Edward L. Greenstein in his work "Texts from Ugarit Solve Biblical Puzzles" explains that in ancient Hebrew, the letter "yud" was originally missing from the name Daniel.

Comment: So in that case should the Danel in the Book of Jubilees be read as Daniel? This book is academically dated to the time of the Maccabees, it seems more to create another puzzle than to solve them.

Comment: @Thales Yes. .!

Comment: Why would something have to change? Ezekiel refers to three righteous individuals from whom both the hearers of the prophecy and we the readers should learn. In what way do you imagine that their historical identity would impact the text itself?

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. This doubt in what the text says and what the tradition wants us to read may have some deep meaning that we don't know the reason for, I would particularly not see a problem identifying the character in question as the Danel of the Jubileus, even because he is together with very well known characters. remote from that time.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. There is of course also the question of what are the odds that the Masoretes knew of these sources in the first place. Where they really "hiding" something? But Jubilees isn't that much of a problem here. The bigger issue is the Ugaritic text, which is blatant idolatry. And I have heard in the past a number of religious Jewish researchers who had no problem with this pagan mythological identification of Daniel, but I've yet to understand their rationale.

Comment: Well, if there are religious Jews who don't see a problem, that solves the problem. The way this professor I mentioned put it suggests that there was a kind of plot not to correlate this individual in Ezequiel with the current Danel of Canaanite tales, a question he did not explain was how the people of the time would have access to this epic. Would this case be the same for this exegete as that text of Judges 18:30, Manasseh or Moses? That's another story and I've even asked this question at another time.

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem at all, but of course, it's your question, so your call. Any Jew might potentially come to hold theologically problematic views which seem to him perfectly okay. Let me try to clarify the problem: If this Daniel is really the Ugaritic Daniel, why in the world would Ezekiel refer to an idolater as a righteous person we must look up to? Noach and Iyov have one thing in common: In the midst of hardship they alone remained faithful to Hashem.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense with regards to Daniel of the Book of Daniel, who remained faithful even while surrounded by Babylonian and later Median idolaters who tried to cause him to stray. But what does this have to do with pagan Canaanite Danel? Yes, Danel of Ahqat did some nice things, but where's the faith in Hashem, the God of Israel? Crickets chirping.

Comment: And Danel from the Book of Jubilees, couldn't he be in that relationship? Was he a correct individual? The whole question of who defends Danel in Ezequiel is because he interprets that Ezequiel, like other biblical books, suffered foreign influence, that is, something of textual criticism unrelated to the objective of the question.

Comment: Danel of Jubilees is at least from a text that recognizes Hashem as the one true God. Perhaps in characterization there's no other connection, but the non-pagan aspect here is also key to a certain extent.

Comment: The question involves Judaism in terms of whether the fact of having a name different from what is proposed by the Masoretes would cause some theological impact of not being what is proposed, at first sight it seems that nothing would change, which already answers my doubt main thing, I just tried to understand the reasons that could have led them to institute a qere in this text.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is still open, I will attempt to explain the issue. In the comments, you expressed relief when I mentioned that I knew of religious (Orthodox) Jews who saw no problem with Daniel of Ezekiel being identified with the Ugaritic Danel. However, I will emphasize again that this does not solve the problem. Unfortunately, I can refer to several religious Jews who hold several theologically-problematic views, particularly with regards to Tanach. I do not know what their answers will be once confronted with the theological question. In some cases, they might perhaps state that the 13 basics of faith are simply the Rambam's view and that not all rabbis agreed with him (cf. Rabbi Yosef Albo who thought that Mashiach is not a basic of faith).

So, what exactly is the problem with Danel?

As I stated in the comments and as stated also by Rabbi Klein in the essay referred to by @Shmuel and stated by others as well, such as Rabbi David Shapira in his book "The Torah of Moshe and the Prophets" (תורת משה והנביאים), p. 268, Danel is nothing more and nothing less than the average Canaanite idolater. He worships Canaanite deities. And this is supposedly the person Ezekiel wants the king of Tyre and later readers to look up to? Very strange conclusion.

There are other flaws in this view as well. For example, the story of Danel has only been found on a single stone tablet so far. How does that prove that the story was popular enough that the king of Tyre, some 800-850 years later, knew it? Another flaw is that Danel is not described as a wise person. Only a single line may perhaps link him to wisdom, in that he was a fair and law-abiding judge who cared for the widows and the orphans. But law-abiding needn't necessarily equal wisdom.

As for the apocryphal Daniel, Rabbi Shapira wrote that the problem with the names that appear in the apocrypha is that many times they were invented by the writers. I don't know how he knows that, though. In any case, this Daniel seems equally irrelevant: He was Enoch's father-in-law, and that's it. We know nothing about his wisdom or any other character traits. Was he even a righteous person? How do we know the king of Tyre knew who he was?

And with regards to the specific person you're referring to, I have no idea what this person actually said/wrote about the Masoretes, but the Masoretes did not invent tradition. They assisted in setting a unified standard out of variant traditions. We may therefore assume that דנאל was the most common spelling in the Book of Ezekiel and דניאל was the most common pronunciation. So this is not some dark Masoretic conspiracy. It's something older. Perhaps it is difficult to argue that the דנאל referred to here is Daniel of the Book of Daniel, but it is also difficult and even problematic to argue that it is the Danel of Ugarit. Some have proposed that it's Daniel/Kilav, one of David's sons, but this is a very midrashic-based understanding and is also flawed. There are a couple of other Daniels mentioned in Tanach, though neither with the spelling דנאל. Either of these could also work just as well as the apocrphyal Daniel, given that they are only mentioned in one verse each and we only know a crumb of biographical info about them.
Who knows, it may very well be none of these and simply a person we are not familiar with from anywhere else in Tanach.

In short, both of these suggestions are flawed, as is the apparent claim that the Masoretes changed the way the text was to be read (strange that they didn't change the way the text was to be spelled!).

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an detailed look into some things you mention in the original question. This might not be an complete answer to your question, but I hope it will help getting there.

You observe:

> Danel appears among non-Israelite characters, Noah and Job

Rashi explains in his commentary [(ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.14.14?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) that these three names are being stated here, because all three of them, were being saved because of their righteousness.

Back to the topic, one of the reasons why there is a difference between דניאל and דנאל, where it is missing a "yud". Rav Yehudah HaChossid, known for his work "Sefer Chasidim" in siman 194 writes:

> אם נכרים יקראו לשום יהודי כשם אלהיהם אל יניח אליהם לקרא שמו כך שהרי כתב החכם אתה מדניאל מדנאל כתיב חסר יו"ד. לפי שמיחה דניאל לנבוכדנאצר מלעשותו אלוה ולא מיחה בו מלקרותו בלטשצאר כשם אלהיו:

Rabbi Reuven Chaim Klein [explains](https://jbqnew.jewishbible.org/assets/Uploads/464/jbq_464_kleindaniel.pdf) in his thesis on this subject that:

> the Bible wrote Daniel’s name as if it was spelled Danel because, although Daniel objected to Nebuchadnezzar making him into a god, he did not protest Nebuchadnezzar calling him Beltshezzar (Dan. 1:7). The name Beltshezzar includes a theophoric element which refers to the name of the Babylonian deity Bel, so Daniel was expected to reject that name, yet we never find that he did. As a result, explains R. Yehudah ha-Hasid, the Bible expresses its dissatisfaction with Daniel’s inaction by erasing the letter yod from his name whenever he appears in Ezekiel

(source: IDENTIFYING THE DANIEL CHARACTER IN EZEKIEL by Rabbi REUVEN CHAIM (RUDOLPH) KLEIN)

Rabbi Reuven Klein quotes R. David Cohen of Brooklyn and explains that Sefer Ezekiel was written in Hebrew, Sefer Daniel was written in Aramaic. In Hebrew, Daniel was written (is written) without an yud and in Aramaic, Daniel is written with an yud. [(see: Ohel David, vol. 6)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52080&st=&pgnum=86&hilite=):

> ת צרה מנוקד הנ״ך בכל דניאל...
> חכם ״הנה כח-ג ביחזקאל מלבד היו״ד
> אל״ף. תחתה שהצרה מדנאל״ אתה
> נדון להיות רוצה אדם שאין ונראה
> הנקודה באה לא ומש״ה הקב״ה ע״י
> דיחזקאל וקרא ככה שהמובן באופן
> על שמרמז רש״י שם מש״כ פי על יל״פ
> לדניאל לעשות רצה שנבוכדנצר מעשה
> וא״כ שם עיין נתרצה לא ודניאל אלוה
> רצה שנבוכדנצר באופן בא דנאל ה

So, would the apochryphal statements be a problem to our tradition(s) and explanations? [Well](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3671027/jewish/What-Is-the-Jewish-Approach-to-the-Apocrypha.htm):

> The Apocrypha isn’t Divinely inspired, and is therefore not part of the canon, and some of its works are even antithetical to Judaism. Other works may indeed contain some valuable information, but they aren’t given any more credence than any other book, and be aware that there have been various additions and deletions made throughout the ages.

Please note that your source isn't considered Jewish at all.

Comment: It's a curious explanation and I love the wealth of Jewish interpretations, they don't deny the difference and try to find explanations, some are very elaborate, I consider this one somewhat elaborate. The question I posed was not so much whether what is written there referred to the Daniel we know, but whether referring to an apocryphal individual present in the Jewish tradition would cause any theological problems?

Comment: @Thales could you clarify in your question that your issue is a theological one with regards to the possible change in identity of דנאל?

Comment: The exegete, in his interpretation of why he thinks that the Masoretes translated Daniel instead of Danel, links this name to the Epic of Aqhat, so for him there would be an attempt to disentangle this individual by inserting a version of a current character in Jewish history.

Comment: "The legend appears to have been a seasonal myth" - https://www.britannica.com/topic/Aqhat-Epic - This is not considered as a Jewish source (see what Harel says). So why bother?

Comment: Well, I just brought what the Masoretes accuse of supposedly having done, if there is merit it is difficult to know, that there is an identification problem in the individual it seems that there is, now putting the intention of why they translated it to another reading only hovers in the field of suggestion, in any case, I was already satisfied to know that there are religious Jews who do not see anything wrong with this individual in Ezequiel not being what is being read but what is written.